# Android layout nested weights breaking (How to make my weights to stay the same)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an issue where I had to make 4 linear layouts and put 4 buttons in each. I need those buttons to be the same sizes, but once they are pressed, they should change image.

I have 2 button icons of the absolutely same size 120x120.
But, when I press on any of them, they suddenly change size comparing to other buttons.

Before click:
[Layout before clicking and changing icon](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul1sozkwls7u5fl/Screenshot%202014-05-12%2009.33.13.png)

After click:
[Layout after click](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p14dexamt7vjo7d/Screenshot%202014-05-12%2009.32.55.png)

You can see how the green buttons are slightly bigger than the white ones.
I need to stop that size changing.

Also, I noticed that the weight of my buttons changes from 1 to 0.92 (for the white buttons).
Is there a way to stop this weight change?

Also, here is my XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/iceland_memory_game"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn31"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn41"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.92"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn32"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn42"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn33"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn43"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn34"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn44"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you have to use GridView instead static layout.

Comment: Yeah, that does sound like an expected method, but I had some reasons for doing it this way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Der Golem's answer, i think it should be `android:layout_height="0dp"` for buttons and `android:layout_width="0dp"` for layouts..because  parent layout is having horizontal orientation and child linear layouts having vertical orientation..

Answer (score 1):

The weighted dimension must be **0dp**, not **wrap_content**.
This is how weights work.

And I'd remove the optional weightSum attribute, since Android calculates it by itself.

**[EDIT]**

Since it only works 1 dimension at a time, this is why it's called "nested" weights.

So, for Buttons, set

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

and for LinearLayouts, set

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Comment: both weight and height ?

Comment: No, it only works 1 dimension at a time, see my edited answer. This is why it's called "nested" weights.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/iceland_memory_game"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```